# Оптимизация записи в файл

Tags: c++, оптимизация, io

Нужно максимально оптимизировать файловый вывод. Начал с обычной очереди сообщений и записи в отдельном потоке с предварительным форматированием. Как и стоило ожидать, скорость не очень большая. На ум приходит собственная реализация `streambuf`, но не сильно надеюсь. Хотелось бы платформонезависимого решения и без скатывания в С (Желательно, но не критично). В какую сторону смотреть и где искать?

**ADD**

Из моей реализации самым ресурсоемким является захват/освобождение мьютекса (Попробовать неблокирующую очередь), `auto command = _queue->front();` (Даже не знаю почему дольше остального) и сам `out << str;`. Т.е. фактические все ест много ресурсов. (Пока без кода, айпад и гитхаб не созданы для друг друга).

Comment: А что вы туда пишите? Даже на обычных иостримах можно легко в диск упереться (особенно если не ssd).

Comment: Платформонезависимое реально быстрым не бывает

Comment: @VTT, просто строки.

Comment: @avp, это понятно, что в серьезном проекте следует выжимать максимум из платформенного api. Но я хочу сделать свою хотелку максимально быстрой для своего класса хотелок)

Comment: *`"Даже не знаю почему дольше остального"`* -- каждое обращение к мьютексу внутри оборачивается системным вызовом

Comment: @avp, я не про мьютекс а про получение первого сообщения в очереди. Он жрет чуть больше чем закрыть мьютекс.

Comment: Если самое ресурсоемкое это операции с мьютексом, то вариантов совсем-совсем мало остается. Если совсем без контекста, то очевиден такой вариант, что мьютекс просто не нужно использовать, а это значит в общем случае, что для каждого потока надо хранить свою версию данных вместо общей.

Comment: Скорее всего, если отказаться от потоков, то все ускорится в разы

Comment: Какова всё же цель «оптимизации»? Развязать основную работу от ввода-вывода или сколь-либо значительно ускорить вывод при каких-то значительных объёмах данных? Вторая задача ИМХО обречена на провал т.к. против скорости диска особо ничего не сделаешь...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, блин, я же вижу, что не в диске дело, вот и написал, что ещё можно сделать, дабы "максимально **возможное**" выжать.

Comment: попробуйте `std::sync_with_stdio(false)` и убрать `std::endl`, если есть. На счет мьютекса, не уверен что это возможно, но посмотрите в сторону [double checked locking](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%81_%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9)

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb, ofstream по-умолчанию без сижронизация с С выводом. Только cout/wcout и тд. + Это было первое что я попробовал) А за double checked locking спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. поток не должен иметь цикла:

`while(strings_to_write==0);`

или хотябы:

```
while(strings_to_write==0)
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::miliseconds(10));
```

2. Как в файл идёт запись. Я использую fstream binary работает достаточно быстро.
3. Не стоит загружать 1000 мелких кусков на запись. Лучше 1 раз сразу всё.
   (Возможно мьютекс не освобождается во время записи 2 потоком, вот и возникает задержка)

Comment: За 3 пункт плюсую.